# Prevent CentOS re-enabling user quotas after reboot/power failure

Tags: centos, quota

I have a client that has an internal server in their office for their Intranet.

Their office recently been through some power cuts in their area recently. Whenever the power goes back on, the server will boot up, and the user quotas will be reset to a default. This is causing problems when their staff are uploading to their Intranet because they have exceeded their quota.

Every time this happens, I disable the quotas, but this gets enabled when the server reboots.

How can I **permanently** disable quotas, including when the server reboots?

The server is running CentOS 6.6.

Here's the contents of `/etc/fstab`

[image]

Comment: Could you cut-and-paste your `/etc/fstab` into your question?

Comment: @MadHatter I've updated the post.

Comment: Thanks, though (a small point) in future it's better to cut-and-paste text into your answer instead of in-lining an image.

Comment: @MadHatter Sorry, I'm using a remote desktop software to ssh into the server. Mad, I know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `grpquota,usrquota,` from the entry for `/home` in your `/etc/fstab` file.  That will permanently disable quota usage on the volume in question.